# Can QDir entryList work with folder shortcut transparently

Tags: c++, qt

I am having a folder in my repository, which in run time has to be located in another path, outside the repository. As I don't want to copy the folder every time my application is running and have duplicates, I have created a shortcut in the second location. However, it seems that the shortcut is not working as a folder, when e.g searching with QDir entryList etc. 
Is there any way for QFiles and QDir to use the shortcut as it would be real folder?
PS: The shortcut idea was inspired from Linux

Comment: Do you mean a windows explorer shortcut? That does not work, it is just a regular file. Use a symlink, windows has been supporting that too for some time now

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it is also supported in Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this from unanswered:

Use a symlink, Windows has been supporting that too for some time now.